# String.replaceAll() method: how to make sure processed characters can never be replaced again

Tags: java, regex, string

I am reading from a file that contains the following two lines: "hello hi" and "hii hey".
The first string of each line is the regex and the second is the replacement, i.e. String.replaceAll("hello", "hi"). I am supposed to go through each line in the file to replace the regex in a String with the replacement. However there is a catch. The processed characters should never be replaced again.

For example I have this String: "helloi".
After the first line, I have "hii".
After the second line, the naive approach would result in "hey".

I want to make sure "hii" still stays as "hii", because it already contains processed characters.

Note that the String I'm using as an example ("helloi") is just a simple one, the actual String will be large and contains multiple lines.

How do you implement that?

Edit: Let me use an example to explain my situation more clearly. I have a String "helloi hii". After the first line in the file, I have "hii hii". But after the second line, I will have "hii hey". The first "hii" contains processed characters, hence it will not be replaced

Comment: You perform all the replacements in 1 pass.

Comment: Good idea. But how do you implement it? My approach is to iterate all lines in the file, inevitably some characters in the String will get replaced more than once.

Comment: The requirement doesn't make sense as stated. You seem to be just wanting to match the first token in each line with itself. You could just as well remove the first token from each line altogether, without worrying about what it is, regular expression, replacements, etc., at all.

Answer (score 1):

I guess every time you call `String.replaceAll` you should insert search and replacement strings into a `HashSet`. Check presence of search and replacement strings in this HashSet, before your call `String.replaceAll`.

Only when both search and replacement strings are not present in HashSet you call `String.replaceAll`.

```
// at start
Set<String> processed = new HashSet<String>(); 

// read file line by line and have this inside your file processing loop

if (!processed.contains(search) && !processed.contains(replacement)) {
   String repl = line.replaceAll(search, replacement);
   processed.add(search);
   processed.add(replacement);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. But I'm looking for ways to prevent characters in a String from being replaced more than once, not restricting the usage of a search-replacement pair to one-time usage only. My actual String is quite large actually, containing multiple lines, so the search-replacement pair may be invoked more than once to replace the other viable characters in the String.

Comment: Actually I am not trying to restrict a pair, otherwise I would have suggested Map. I think based on your description you may just need to check for search string in HashSet so that same search isn't replaced again.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not clear enough. Let me use an example to explain my situation more clearly. I have a String "helloi hii". After the first line in the file, I have "hii hii". But after the second line, I will have "hii hey". The first "hii" contains processed characters, hence it will not be replaced

Comment: Hmm in that case same HashSet approach but instead of search and replacement strings insert replaced String `repl` into Set. Will that work?

Comment: Mmm.. think it will prevent unprocessed Strings with same characters as String repl from being processed.

Comment: Why would that be? Consider using word boundaries in search string so that `foo` doesn't stop `food` to be processed again.

Comment: But what about "hii" (processed) and "hii" (unprocessed)? The latter will be restricted...

Comment: But if `"hii"` comes again as search string then you do want to restrict it right?

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure I understand, but can you make your own class with a string property and a boolean property to indicate if it's been modified?  Split your string into an array of that class and process each one.

Answer (score 1):

String.replaceAll() probably won't do the job for you.

I would suggest something similar to this psuedo-code

```
replacements -> HashMap<String, String>
StringBuffer result
regexStr = "("
for each key in replacements
    regexStr += key + "|" //key MUST not have any regex syntax or must be properly escaped
regexStr remove last '|' append ")"
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regexStr).matcher()
while(matches) {
    get next match
    result.append(match group 1)
    result.append(replacements.get(match group 2))
}
```

Essentially:

Keep a map of all of your replacements:

```
hi->woah
hello->hi
hey->what's up
what\'s up->fun
```

You search for strings matching the regex `(.*?)(hi|hello|hey|what\'s up)`, which is all of the map keys (i.e. the things you want to search for). The \ would end up in a Java literal as `"what\\s up"`, because the regex string needs to know to escape the `'`

Each iteration, look at what was captured. The first group is everything since the last match. The second group is the word/phrase to replace. If the word it "hi", you want to replace it with "woah", so look up the replacement for "hi" in your map.